# dplyr: NA in some groups can affect mutate results in other groups

Tags: r, dplyr

#### update: This problem is related to older versions of dplyr (<=0.4.3) and R (<=3.1.3).

When some groups have NA values, `dplyr::mutate()` can return incorrect results depending on which groups are considered. I didn't find a similar question on StackOverflow after a cursory search, though it may be related to the dplyr issue [#1545](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1545). Any explanation of this pattern would be much appreciated.

The example below calculates a group mean through `mutate`. (Using `summarize` instead of `mutate` did not result in this problem.)

```
library(dplyr)

#Sample function: calculate group means    
foo <- function(data, groups) { 
      data %>% 
        filter(Group %in% groups) %>%
        group_by(Group) %>%
        mutate(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
}

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(1:4, each = 2), 
                 value = c(rep(NA, 2), sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE)))
df
#  Group value
#1     1    NA
#2     1    NA
#3     2     3
#4     2     4
#5     3     6
#6     3    10
#7     4     3
#8     4     9
```

In this data.frame, group 1 consists of NA values. Running `foo` on group 1 should yield NA values while Groups 2, 3, 4 should yield 3.5, 8, 6 respectively. However, actual results vary depending on which groups are included:

```
foo(df, 1:4)      #group 3 fails
#  Group value  mean
#  (int) (int) (dbl)
#1     1    NA    NA
#2     1    NA    NA
#3     2     3   3.5
#4     2     4   3.5
#5     3     6    NA  #<-- should be 8
#6     3    10    NA  #<-- should be 8
#7     4     3   6.0
#8     4     9   6.0

foo(df, 2:4)      #correct
foo(df, 3:1)      #group 3 fails
foo(df, c(1,3))   #group 3 fails
foo(df, c(2,3))   #correct
foo(df, c(3,4))   #correct
foo(df, c(1,2))   #group 2 fails
foo(df, c(1,3,4)) #correct
foo(df, c(1,2,4)) #correct
```

After testing various types of `df` with different orderings of NA values, it looks like means are not calculated for certain groups when earlier groups have NA values. But why the differences in output? For example, group 3 tends to fail in the above examples while group 2's mean is successfully calculated.

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
#
#locale:
#  [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#
#attached base packages:
#  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#
#other attached packages:
#  [1] dplyr_0.4.3
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.4         magrittr_1.5    parallel_3.1.3  R6_2.1.2       
#[6] Rcpp_0.12.4     rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.1.3
```

Comment: I get the correct output with your code. Group 3 mean is 8. Group 1 mean is `NaN`. I'm on OSX Yosemite, R 3.3.1, dplyr 0.5.0. `dplyr` is the only extra package I've loaded.

Comment: You probably just need to update `dplyr`.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks for checking. RStudio didn't list any updates, so it looks like I have a problem with my libraries.

Comment: Also works fine for me with dplyr `0.5.0`. You can just delete your existing dplyr from your libraries folder and just reinstall.

Comment: Addendum: I couldn't upgrade dplyr on two separate Windows computers (even manually) until I upgraded R to 3.3.1. Afterwards, the above example works. Will leave this question up unless it should be withdrawn.